# Setting up a connection to an SMB1 server in my iOS app

Tags: ios, swift, smb, file-sharing

I am trying to create a custom connection to a server that is SMB1. I want to be able to connect a button action to make this connection and bring up the files in a document picker. I feel like I have scoured the internet and can't find any sort of documentation or help here. I would love to do it through the files app built in to iOS but sadly it won't make the connection with this SMB1 server.

I'm really trying to not use a cocoapod or some other external code source if possible. I know this may be a futile task, but I know it is possible since FileExplorer is able to make this connection easily.

Thanks in advance!

Honestly I don't even know where to start with this. Any help or a point in the right direction would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow! See [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

It might be worth looking at the VS File Manager application. It allows connections to all SMB servers.
https://apps.apple.com/pk/app/vs-file-manager/id1621823117